# Issue with linphone chat messages

Tags: ios

I'm developing an iPhone app which uses linphone in order to communicate, voice and video both work well, but text messages do not.

Only the last text message is sent. It happens while using liblinphone in our iPhone application, but also in linphone for windows and mac.

Could you suggest a workaround o way to fix it?

Thanks,
Leonardo.

Answer (score 3):

I'm answering my own question because it may be useful for someone else. The bug was acknowledged and solved by Linphone creators.
Now it is working well. You can update/check out.

Comment: can you help me for video call and message chat in swift?